# NullReferenceException when trying to install Visual Studio extension in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

So I'm trying to install my Visual Studio extension in Visual Studio 2015 but I'm getting this install error when trying:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

The strange thing is that I can run the extension in the experimental instance when debugging.

This is in the install log:

```
Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015...
Install Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForValidDotNetFramework(IExtension extension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForInstallBlockers(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, Boolean isNestedExtension, Boolean& olderVersionInstalled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean perMachine, Boolean isNestedExtension, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, UInt64 totalBytesToWrite, UInt64& totalBytesWritten, Boolean enforceCertificateCheckForUpgrade)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Boolean enforceCertificateCheckForUpgrade)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Boolean enforceCertificateCheckForUpgrade)
```

Things I already tried:

- Repairing Visual Studio
- Trying it on another PC (same error)
- Trying to install it in safemode (`devenv /safemode`)
- `devenv /resetsettings`
- Trying to install via doubleclick on the vsix file instead of via a private extension gallery
- Uninstalling the extension "Developer Analytics Tools"
- Trying an older version of the code which I'm pretty sure once worked
- Checking all references, clean, rebuild
- Removing nuget packages and readding them (Newtonsoft.Json & 1 other)

Please help.

Comment: Does it work in debug mode? in addition, please try to  rename or delete the file named 'MachineState.json' in your <VS2015 Install Dir>/Common7/IDE/Extensions/ folder? for more information, please refer to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098661/failed-to-install-visual-studio-extensions-vsix

Comment: Yes it worked in debug mode and renaming 'MachineState.json' didn't help. I was able to fix it just now (see below for how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so now I inspected ExtensionManager.Implementation and from the CheckForValidDotNetFramework method I worked out that the Version range of the .NET Framework wasn't set for the extension. I could set it in `source.extension.vsixmanifest` under `Dependencies` where I entered `[4.6.1]` in `Version range` of the entry after changing the .NET framework to that on all projects.

It would have been helpful if the error message in the log said *which* object was null.